# java Scrollbars not co-operating

Tags: java, jscrollpane, jtextarea

Hello Im trying to create a JTextArea which once the data gets to large to hold the data the scroll bars can allow me to scroll however ATM there are no scroll bars just a little square box and the data is pushing the rest of the GUI up.

This is the code for the textArea and the scrollbars, p3 is the panel im trying to add the scrollbar and textArea too.

```
//TEXT AREA
final JTextArea dataTextField = new JTextArea();
dataTextField.setSize(750,200);    
dataTextField.setLineWrap(true);
dataTextField.setEditable(false);
dataTextField.setVisible(true);

JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane (dataTextField);
scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
    JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
scroll.setVisible(true);

p3.add(dataTextField);
p3.add(scroll);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
//p3.add(dataTextField);
p3.add(scroll);
```

A swing component can only have a single parent. When you add the dataTextField to the panel you remove it from the scrollpane. Get rid of that line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `setSize (750, 200)` on `dataTextField`.  Just pass number of columns and rows to constructor of `JTextArea`.

Comment: If i want it to span the who;e area of p3, would that be setRow=1 and setColum=1?

I tired to use p3.getHeight and width but it just the width isnt correct